# LBFGS Giving Tensor Object not Callable Error when using Optimizer.step

Tags: optimization, pytorch, closures

I am trying to use `sgd, adam`, and `LBFGS` optimizer.

The part of the code is:

```
for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(trainloader):
            batch_size = inputs.size(0)
            total += batch_size
            one_hot_targets = torch.FloatTensor(batch_size, 10).zero_()
            one_hot_targets = one_hot_targets.scatter_(1, targets.view(batch_size, 1), 1.0)
            one_hot_targets = one_hot_targets.float()
            if use_cuda:
                inputs, one_hot_targets = inputs.cuda(), one_hot_targets.cuda()
            inputs, one_hot_targets = Variable(inputs), Variable(one_hot_targets)
            
            
            if optimizer_val=='sgd' or optimizer_val=='adam':
              outputs = F.softmax(net(inputs))
              loss = criterion(outputs, one_hot_targets)

              loss.backward()
              optimizer.step()

            else:
              def closure():
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                outputs = F.softmax(net(inputs))
                loss = criterion(outputs, one_hot_targets)
                loss.backward()
                return loss    

              optimizer.step(closure())
```

In the `optimizer.step(closure())` part in `LBFGS` (running in `else`) I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

I checked, the `loss` is tensor type.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function callback to the [`optimizer.step`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#optimizer-step-closure) function, don't call it:

```
optimizer.step(closure)
```